# Using search trees to expedite coding for rubik's cube solving algorithm

Tags: design

I'm a mechanical engineering student currently building a rubik's cube solver. I'd like to code a VSCode program (meant to interface with an arduino mega) that uses the basic CFOP method (solves cross -> corners -> second layer edges -> OLL -> PLL).

The simplest way of going about it would be to pretty much hardcode in a sequence of moves for each piece of the cube. For the first 4 edges and corners, this would be an absolutely ridiculous amount of code. Take the white-orange-blue corner; there are 8 possible positions in 3 different orientations, leading to 24 completely unique sequences of moves I'd have to account for. All in all, I predict it would end up being a 3000+ line program.

Would it be possible to, instead of simply knowing how to solve every piece in order, take a piece and mess around with it until it's placed where it needs to go, and trace the shortest path back and set *that* as the move sequence? for edges and corners, most can be solved within 2-4 moves, and given the standard movement notation, each piece has only 4 degrees of freedom at a time, so I don't think it should be too computationally intensive?

The problem is, I have zero experience with trees, theory, or implementation, and have zero idea if this would even be possible. However, if it is, it would make coding this soooo much less tedious.

Answer (score 1):

*"take a piece and mess around with"* will not work with the Rubik's cube problem - when you "mess around" with arbitrary moves, you destroy the order of the pieces you already placed correctly beforehand. Building a full search tree won't work either, that tree would require [43,252,003,274,489,856,000 nodes](https://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2011/10/every-possible-state-of-a-standard-rubiks-cube-can-be-solved-in-20-moves-or-less/) due to exponential growth.

So you typically need to apply specific move sequences which don't destroy the achieved partial solution. But there is no need to write individual code for every possible position and orientation of a piece. Just approach it like a human would do it, following one of the well-known solution algorithms

- have a general description of certain move sequences stored in some notation, for achieving certain intermediate goals
- implement a program which is able to interpret such move sequences and apply it to the "Rubik's cube simulator" of your program
- implement a part of the program which allows you to explorate the symmetry of the cube, so you can apply the same move sequence to different symmetric cases
- when solving the upper two layers, you can utilize of the fact the lower layer can be rotated arbitrarily before a predefined move sequence gets applied.
- finally, make your program choose one piece after another, pick a suitable move sequence which places and orients it correctly, and apply that move sequence.

It may be also a good idea to start with a simpler comparable problem first, for example the ["15 puzzle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle), and collect some experience with it, before trying to solve harder problems like Rubik's cube.